# setting apache to read from my user's directory

Tags: apache-2.2

I have Centos 5 running `Apache/2.2.3`. Now the default folder is `/var/www/html` and whatever I put in it shows when I browse it from the web.

Now I would like to to create a folder `www` under my user `bob` and have all files loaded from that folder;

```
/home/bob/www
```

When I change the document root folder in my httpd.config I get an 403 error, I have even tried with virtualhosts but the same error shows.

Any ideas on what to do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apache runs under user who does not have right to read home folder of bob. you can change rights of this folder so everyone can read from it or better create group to which both apache's user and bob belong and then change ownership of /home/bob/www so that group can read and list it's content.